# Replace all for-loops, numpy using map(), reduce(), and filter()

Tags: python, functools

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances_argmin

def find_clusters(X, n_clusters, rseed=2):
    # 1. Randomly choose clusters
    rng = np.random.RandomState(rseed)
    i = rng.permutation(X.shape[0])[:n_clusters]
    centers = X[i]
    
    while True:
        # 2a. Assign labels based on closest center
        labels = pairwise_distances_argmin(X, centers)
        
        # 2b. Find new centers from means of points
        new_centers = np.array([X[labels == i].mean(0)
                                for i in range(n_clusters)])
        
        # 2c. Check for convergence
        if np.all(centers == new_centers):
            break
        centers = new_centers
    
    return centers, labels

centers, labels = find_clusters(X, 4)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=labels,
            s=50, cmap='viridis');
```

I'm having trouble re-writing

```
new_centers = np.array([X[labels == i].mean(0) for i in range(n_clusters)])
```

without for-loops, and numpy using `map()`, `reduce()`,and `filter()`.

How to do it?

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with you code...

Comment: I want to replace of numpy and list indexing and for loops and only use map(), reduce(), and filter() to compute new_centers.

Comment: why would you want to replace efficient, clear and concise numpy code with slower, arguably more obscure and lengthy native python code?

Comment: to make it in the mapreduce paradigm that can be parallel distributed on multiple computers.

Comment: @Germania Why don't you use `dask` which is `sklearn` like library for parallel computing or if you want to make use of `gpu`s, then NVIDIA `RAPIDS` is a good choice.